Visual Studio Code поехал головой (и ноутбук в целом)
Сразу укажу: ноутбуку чуть больше полугода (win11), на днях проверил через Defender - обнаружило лишь один троян (который, говорят, виндовс часто выдает за троян, а на самом деле это ошибка), вследствие чего удалил его. Перейдем к проблеме.
При покупке ноутбука мне поставили win11, активировали её, все дела. Абсолютно всё работало исправно, до недавних пор. Около месяца назад у меня вылезло сообщение с активацией виндовс (первый вопрос - если мне активировали его при покупке, то может ли это сообщение вовсе вылезти, тем более через такой короткий срок?)
Я активировал винду через cmd по видео в ютубе, через какую-то базу бесплатных ключей от самого майкрософт чтоли. Вроде всё прошло хорошо, однако после этого ноутбук начал вытворять какую-то полную херню: проводник запускался с пролагами текстур, приложения почему-то стали открываться только через второй запуск (хотя запускались с одного, ярлыки на них у меня в меню пуск, а рабочий стол чист). Второй вопрос - с моим ноутбуком что-то не так, или же те, кто пишет о том, что виндовс11 очень баганная до сих пор и постоянно что-то обновляет на фоне - правы? Оперативы не может не хватать, ноутбук рабочий, на нём я даже умудрялся летом играть с друзьями в рафт. Также меня раздражает то, что к моей вайфай-сети бывает ноутбук не находит соединение ("Нет доступа к интернету"), хотя с роутером всё в порядке и на телефоне доступ к сети есть.
Кроме того, главный вопрос у меня возникает с VS Code, который я установил с официального источника. Я 3 месяца отходил на курсы фронтенда, где VSCode исправно работал и никогда меня не подводил. После курсов началось то, что описано выше (начиная с активации виндовс) - именно после этого VSCode начал вести себя неадекватно (скрины ошибок загрузил в личку в вк, откуда на них будут ссылки):

Очень часто при выходе с VSCode начало появляться окно с обновлением программы (inno_updater), чего раньше никогда не было. Мало того, это окно не завершается никакими путями - ни само не грузится, ни через "снять задачу". Мало того - оно напрочь удаляет ярлык VSCode с меню пуск, а также удаляет приложение до полной его переустановки:

https://sun9-40.userapi.com/impg/f1pX6QR58qw6P_JUgIx1IgsvjUhsFvcEI-5Dvw/GiZdMmJ94VQ.jpg?size=336x155&quality=96&sign=fe9ba62a080d07229ceaff034dc0844f&type=album

При открытии проектов и вовсе VSCode, а конкретно проблема касается расширений ("Хост-процесс расширений что-то там...), которые всегда исправно работали, эти расширения непонятно почему выходят из строя:

https://sun9-5.userapi.com/impg/6YXRkomaL_AqUha310eTtDAXggUF20wRAOkKmQ/a4oNa6e-Mqw.jpg?size=556x324&quality=96&sign=e4110db17b836949399d46f576f19556&type=album

Терминал Git Bash и любой другой (в VSC установлен именно GIt Bash) перестал запускаться (запускается, наверное, с 5% шансом), а попытки его удалить и перезапустить или вовсе килльнуть через ctrl+c ни к чему не приводят (при этом сам bash.exe кое-как запустился с самой cmd):

https://sun9-45.userapi.com/impg/pWE5RcTtUO7cWq1Vyd3LhpAK_GwojgKwGm-GhA/ZhacY8gVWgQ.jpg?size=1540x200&quality=96&sign=73993ca2eeb4e4023a4b742345ff73f6&type=album
3.1 В некоторых случаях киллы терминала приводят к следующей ошибке:
https://sun9-8.userapi.com/impg/aJrwotmKrsM1ihoKFaX0ff3LDR9rpTmpHC2u1A/ZHegV7TuDVk.jpg?size=563x131&quality=96&sign=595713edf6053b14b70954bbb219dee8&type=album
Сама справка перекидывает на страницу, где решением ставят как раз указание нужного терминала для запуска, что у меня итак выполнено. Стоит подчеркнуть, что с ошибкой терминала связана ошибка в нём же, которая появляется спустя много спама киллом ctrl+c:0 [bash] bash 1518 dofork: child -1 - forked process 14456 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000005, errno 11 bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
И вот вопрос: это VSCode как-то обновили в последнее время, что всё намертво у него отказало, или в чем тогда проблема еще может быть, если раньше всё исправно работало?

как задать хороший вопрос

переустанови винду :D
